# Task.WaitAsync vs Task.Wait

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I know that `Task.Wait()` block thread in which it is executed.

Do I understand correctly that `Task.WaitAsync()` does not do this?

I tried to find information about it but I didn't find anything

Comment: `Task.WaitAsync()` is useful when you want to make a `Task` *cancellable based on a timeout* and executes without blocking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[WaitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-6.0) will return a *new* task that needs to be awaited in turn. It's not used to avoid `await`, it's used to allow cancelling a wait for another task.

If you want you await for a task to complete without blocking you'll have to use `await` in an `async` method, or use `ContinueWith` with the continuation code:

```
async Task MyMethodAsync(Task myTask)
{
   ...
   await myTask;
   ...
}
```

This code can await forever and doesn't allow cancelling the wait. If you want to stop waiting after a while you can use `Task.WaitAsync`

```
...
try
{
    await myTask.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinute(1));
}
catch(TimeoutException)
{
    //Handle the timeout
}
...
```

Or you may want to cancel awaiting that task if a parent call signals cancellation through a `CancellationTokenSource`

```
async Task MyMethod(Task someTask,CancellationToken cancellationToken=default)
{
   ....
   await someTask.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is non-blocking since it returns a `Task`. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-6.0).

```
public Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
public Task WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout);
public Task WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

> Gets a `Task` that will complete when this `Task` completes, when the specified timeout expires, or when the specified `CancellationToken` has cancellation requested.

The implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Common/tests/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskTimeoutExtensions.cs):

```
public static Task WaitAsync(this Task task, int millisecondsTimeout) =>
    WaitAsync(task, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondsTimeout), default);

public static Task WaitAsync(this Task task, TimeSpan timeout) =>
    WaitAsync(task, timeout, default);

public static Task WaitAsync(this Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
    WaitAsync(task, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, cancellationToken);

public async static Task WaitAsync(this Task task, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    using (new Timer(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetException(new TimeoutException()), tcs, timeout, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan))
    using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetCanceled(), tcs))
    {
        await(await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```